# Accessing the Twitter API - authenticating and backbone models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, twitter, oauth

I am trying to learn Backbone as well as the Twitter API and am running into some issues.

First of all, I was only able to generate a access token so far, so I got part of OAuth done, but am having trouble making a request to get tweets.

I'm using some code I found online to help get me started
Here is a collection:

```
var Twitter = new Backbone.Model({
    api: api,
    token: tokenToUse,
    debug: false
});
// define a collection
Twitter.Collection = Collection.extend({

    initialize: function(models, options){

        options = options || {};
        _.extend(this.options, options);

        return Collection.prototype.initialize.apply( arguments );
    },

    sync : function( method, model, options ) {

        options.dataType = 'jsonp';

        return Backbone.sync( method, model, options );

    }
});
```

Then I define a search collection

```
Twitter.Collections.Search = Twitter.Collection.extend({
    model: Backbone.API.Twitter.Models.Tweet, // this is defined elsewhere

    url: function(){ return "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q="+ encodeURIComponent(this.options.query) + "result_type=mixed&count=100"; },

    options: {
        query : "",
        num : 10
    },

    parse: function( data ){
        if( Twitter.get("debug") )
            console.log("Twitter.Collections.Search: ", data );
        return data.results;
    },

    initialize: function(query){
        this.options.query = query;
    }

});
```

The issue I have is that the Twitter API needs authentication, and I need to add authorization headers... now the question is how to do that? I'm unsure where to set the headers to get this working.

The API documentation is quite large and there is lots of data which needs to be generated first, setting up OAuth is proving to be a huge pain.

Is there perhaps a JavaScript library which has this setup somewhere?

These are the request headers from my console:

Request URL:https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=testresult_type=mixed&count=100&callback=jQuery19100829295557923615_1420770637354&_=1420770637355
Request Method:GET
**Status Code:400 Bad Request**
Request Headers
:host:api.twitter.com
:method:GET
:path:/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=testresult_type=mixed&count=100&callback=jQuery19100829295557923615_1420770637354&_=1420770637355
:scheme:https
:version:HTTP/1.1
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
referer: someSite
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 1):

instead of constructing the query in you `url` method, try assigning it in the `fetch` call along with extra headers

```
Collection.extend({
    sync: function (method, model, options) {
         options.dataType = 'jsonp';
         options.headers = {
            "auth-key": "c12a9e06-****-443e-bb2d-5220c70f****"
        }
        return Backbone.sync( method, model, options );
    }
});

model.fetch({
    data: {
        q: "whatever",
        result_type: 'mixed',
        count: 100
    }
})
```